# How to turn off line numbering in interactive prompt (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-interactive

How do I stop this "In [2]:" line numbering? I was trying to follow some shortcuts in the interactive prompt from stack overflow and now my interactive prompt is freezing after this started to appear.

Visual Studio 2017 'Interactive'

It's frozen right now from pressing 'Enter' after x = 5.

```
>>> import numpy

In [2]: x = 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new interactive window instead of trying to fix the problem.
Click the 'Open interactive window' and hide the interactive prompt that is showing the issue above.

[image]